# Multisite, but wp_kses_allowed_html only for one subsite?

Tags: multisite, wp-kses

Upon trying to add the capability of unfiltered_html to a given role on a given subsite, and finding that's deprecated, I found this WP Support Topic: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/multisite-allow-editors-to-post-iframe-embeds/

Which provides the following code snippet:

```
function allow_iframes_for_editor( $allowed_tags ){
    
    $allowed_tags['iframe'] = array(
        'align' => true,
        'allow' => true,
        'allowfullscreen' => true,
        'class' => true,
        'frameborder' => true,
        'height' => true,
        'id' => true,
        'marginheight' => true,
        'marginwidth' => true,
        'name' => true,
        'scrolling' => true,
        'src' => true,
        'style' => true,
        'width' => true,
        'allowFullScreen' => true,
        'class' => true,
        'frameborder' => true,
        'height' => true,
        'mozallowfullscreen' => true,
        'src' => true,
        'title' => true,
        'webkitAllowFullScreen' => true,
        'width' => true
    );
    
    if ( current_user_can('edit_posts') ) {
      return $allowed_tags;  
    }
}

add_filter( 'wp_kses_allowed_html', allow_iframes_for_editor, 1 );
```

and that works great to allow a user to insert an iframe into Gutenberg's Custom HTML block without that user being a Super Admin on the multisite network. The original snippet used the editor role, but I changed it so it wasn't role-specific, since we have some custom roles.

**BUT** ... I want this to apply to site 101 only ...

Generally I would add `if ( 101 == $blog_id ) {}` and be good to go. I tell you I've added that condition in every logical and reasonable place (and some ridiculous) and I cannot for the life of me limit the iframe tag to ONLY site 101.

I'm once again hoping I've made a rudimentary error I cannot see that I'll feel silly for even asking ... nevertheless, any insight and assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: there are better ways to insert iframes into sites than `unfiltered_html` which is a very dangerous capability to add to a user. Likewise modifying `wp_kses_allowed_html` has major consequences for security and is very dangerous. Have you considered a custom shortcode/OEmbed/block instead?

Comment: @TomJNowell thank you for bringing that up. While the user base is "internal" and relatively controlled and trusted, I'm all for taking the more secure route. Much appreciated. Knowing I have yet to make a custom block ... would you recommend going the shortcode route? Or is this a good / simple enough scenario to cut my teeth on custom blocks?

Comment: shortcodes, blocks, widgets, whatever works, they're _all_ better than putting iframes directly into post content. There are lots of prebuilt solutions out there, e.g. there are a lot of 3rd party implementations of the `[iframe]` shortcode, and most common iframe insertions are actually people trying to embed popular vendors that already have blocks or support OEmbed, e.g. Youtube. You may find that copy pasting a plain URL to what you embed on a blank line on its own is enough to create an embed iframe. Note that it doesn't matter how much you trust your users when it comes to security

Comment: This particular instance is a Google Drive Video and for some reason the embed block says it cannot embed it. Tried that too.

Comment: yup you'll need to find other options, there are lots of questions asking how to embed iframes on the site already

Comment: Landed on this well-reviewed and aptly, simply named plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/iframe/ ... testing now. Much thanks for the caveat.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do it this way:

```
if ( 101 === get_current_blog_id() ) {
  add_filter( 'wp_kses_allowed_html', allow_iframes_for_editor, 1 );
}
```

**(Note: edited to use the get_current_blog_id() ; see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_blog_id/**

But you should consider Tom's comment as a warning against doing this.

Comment: Definitely tried this, but tried it yet again just now to confirm. It didn't restrict it to 101 at all. I was able to embed the same iframe on blog 1.

Comment: See edited answer; using get_current_blog_id function, which returns an integer. Also, use "===" for exact comparison.

Comment: The interesting thing here is that I use global $blog_id and conditionals in a number of other sites without issue. But I am heeding Tom's comments here and going another route.

Comment: For anyone lurking and trying out the code, do a var_dump of the $blog_id variable (after a 'global' if needed) and a 'die()' to see what the value is. Maybe it's a timing function of when the filter actually occurs - too soon for the value to be accurate?